# Kissing Number: Theorem suggestions

Tags: geometry

Our professor is asking us to study some topics about the Kissing Number, particularly, our prof wants us to find out some theorems or topics that we can do a little research or study, and after that we can hopefully get to the stage in which we can prove those theorems or conditions studies.

I have finished study and proved that the maximum number of kissing number in two dimension is 6.

I am asking for some suggestions or theorems that I can learn and study about this Kissing Number, since I really have no idea where to start finding these kind of topics.

P.S. The topics should be within the undergraduate level.

Thanks for suggesting and helping. :)

Comment: what is the number in dimension $3$?  You may prove a lower and an upper estimate.

Comment: Besides the proof in higher dimension, is there anything else we can learn for this topic?